# How to hide tab order after edit in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

Very simple question:

**How can I hide the tab order numbers in Qt Designer preview?**

I've changed the order without problems but I cant find a way to hide the green numbers. Unchecking *Edit > Edit Tab Order* does not work.

Comment: No you are confused, in _Designer_ you can switch _editing_ between {widgets, buddies, Tab order ...etc}, its not like _unchecking_ . so if you want to leave tab order editor and go back to widget editor, you just click _edit widgets_

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT DOWNVOTE** because this is on topic in StackOverflow. This question is about a `"...software tool commonly used by programmers..."` (from **[stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four buttons next to each other on the toolbar which control the editing mode:

- Edit Widgets
- Edit Signals/Slots
- Edit Buddies
- Edit Tab Order

So you just need to select one of the others to exit tab-order mode. The normal/default mode is widget mode.

Comment: same for my question, maybe they think that this is off topic, but [stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) tells the opposite.

Comment: Thank for the reply, it is misleading because appears a checkmark near "Edit Tab Order" and you can uncheck it, but the numbers do not disappear.

Comment: @Guglie. Glad to help. Sorry about all the ignorant downvoting.